# vertical align div, outer div not growing

Tags: html, css

I have a few nested `divs` and i need to vertically center one of the nested `divs`. Normally i'd do this by giving the outer `div` the css property `position: relative` and the inner `div` the property `position: absolute`. I can then easily use `top` and `left` to position the `div`.

But i can't get it done with my current structure. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Epmd4/2/

So basically from that example, the div with the blue border should be vertically centered inside the green div. But i can't get it done.

Anyone any idea how to do this?

PS. I can **only** add css properties to the `.item` div and everything inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.item {
    /*position: relative;*/
    background: #00FF66;
    min-height: 60px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Epmd4/4/)**

For this to work in IE7, a JavaScript hack is necessary:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7) {
      $(".tablecell").wrap("<td />");
      $(".tablerow").wrap("<tr />");
      $(".table").wrapInner("<table />");
  }
});
```

Just replace the `.table*` classes with the appropriate ones.

Comment: Why oh why did you beat me to it?

Comment: It works, but not in IE7. And unfortunately i have to support that too... :'-(

Comment: @Vivendi Would you be okay with some JavaScript?

Comment: @Abody97 Sure, if it can't be done with just CSS and HTML then JS is the best alternative. (i'm using jQuery btw)

Comment: @Vivendi - You're right about the IE7 thing. Sorry, I don't have that to test with.

Comment: @j08691 IE9, press F12 and select Browser Mode: IE7.

Comment: @Ana - yes I'm aware of that, however I prefer to test with the real deal in a vm.